# Transferring from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I'm trying to find out and breaking each method while running my codes, and I still can't find why setTempID is always 0, I already assigned a value to it.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

//imports
using DHELTASSys.DataAccess;
using DHELTASSys.Modules;
using DHELTASSys.AuditTrail;

namespace Enrollment
{
    public partial class HRLogin : Form
    {
        HRModuleBL obj = new HRModuleBL();
        DHELTASSysAuditTrail audit = new DHELTASSysAuditTrail();

        public HRLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            obj.Emp_id = int.Parse(txtEmpID.Text);
            audit.Emp_id = int.Parse(txtEmpID.Text);
            obj.Password = txtPassword.Text;

            if (obj.AccountEnrollmentLogin().Rows.Count == 0) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is incorrect!");
            }
            else if (obj.CheckIfHRManager().Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed to access this system!");
            }
            else
            {
                CreateAccount frm = new CreateAccount();

                frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm_FormClosed);

                audit.AddAuditTrail("Has logged in into the Fingerprint Enrollment System.");

                frm.setEmpID = int.Parse(txtEmpID.Text);

                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }  
        }

        void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

and here is the other form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

//imports
using DHELTASSys.AuditTrail;
using DHELTASSys.Modules;

namespace Enrollment
{
    delegate void Function();   // a simple delegate for marshalling calls from event handlers to the GUI thread

    public partial class CreateAccount : Form
    {
        HRModuleBL obj = new HRModuleBL();
        DHELTASSysAuditTrail audit = new DHELTASSysAuditTrail();

        private int emp_id;

        public int setEmpID
        {
            set { emp_id = value;}
        }

        public CreateAccount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }


        private void OnTemplate(DPFP.Template template)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate()
            {
                Template = template;
                VerifyButton.Enabled = SaveButton.Enabled = (Template != null);
                if (Template != null)
                    MessageBox.Show("The fingerprint template is ready for verification and saving", "Fingerprint Enrollment");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("The fingerprint template is not valid. Repeat fingerprint enrollment.", "Fingerprint Enrollment");
            }));
        }

        private DPFP.Template Template;








        private void EnrollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnrollmentForm Enroller = new EnrollmentForm();
            Enroller.OnTemplate += this.OnTemplate;
            Enroller.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            obj.Last_name = txtLastname.Text;
            obj.First_name = txtFirstName.Text;
            obj.Middle_name = txtMiddleName.Text;
            obj.Position_name = cmbPosition.Text;
            obj.Company_name = cmbCompany.Text;
            obj.Password = txtTempPassword.Text;
            obj.Department_name = cmbDepartment.Text;

            if (obj.Last_name == string.Empty) //Validation for empty texts
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Last name can't be empty!");
            } else if (obj.First_name == string.Empty) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First name can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (obj.Middle_name == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Middle name can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (obj.Position_name == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Position name can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (obj.Department_name == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deparment can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (obj.Company_name == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Company name can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (obj.Password == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password can't be empty!");
            }
            else if (txtConfirmTempPassword.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please verify your input password!");
            }
            else
            {

                if (txtTempPassword.Text != txtConfirmTempPassword.Text)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Password does not match", "Password Mismatch",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
                    Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
                    fingerprintData.Position = 0;
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
                    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);

                    audit.Emp_id = emp_id;

                    obj.Biometric_code = bytes;
                    obj.AddAccountSetTempPassword();
                }
            }
        }

        private void VerifyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerificationForm Verifier = new VerificationForm();
            Verifier.Verify(Template);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting it to frm.setEmpID so that I could get it from another form.

Thanks for the help man.

Comment: Might be worth display the code in the `setEmpID` property on your `CreateAccount` form.

Comment: @MartinParkin added the `CreateAccount` form man

Comment: You may wish to consider adding a `get` accessor to the `setEmpID` property.  It could be that `emp_id` is being set to the value but you will never be able to access it through the `setEmpID` property as it is write-only.

Comment: do the `Emp_id` on other classes get the correct value?

Comment: The code in CreateAccount form receives the variable but where do you want to display it?

Comment: @etaiso no it didn't get the right values.

Comment: @Steve i'm assigning it to the `audit` object of the class `AuditTrail` so that the function `AddAccountSetTempPassword` may access it since my business logic is also using the `AuditTrail` class.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Let me understand. the class `HRModuleBL` (obj) has the method `AddAccountSetTempPassword`, you assign the value of the local variable emp_id (whose value has been set via the property) to an instance of the class `DHELTASSysAuditTrail`. I fail to see the relation between these two classes

Comment: The `HRModuleBL` class is also using the `DHELTASSysAuditTrail` class, wherein the method `AddAccountSetTempPassword` is using the `AddAuditTrail` method of the `DHELTASSysAuditTrail` that requires a emp_id to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your `SaveButton_Click` event in the `CreateAccount` form you need to set also the `Emp_Id` variable of the obj instance defined inside that form (as you have done in the instance of the `HRModuleBL` defined in the first form).

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....
    audit.Emp_id = emp_id;
    obj.Emp_id = emp_id;
    obj.Biometric_code = bytes;
    obj.AddAccountSetTempPassword();
    .....
}
```